# Handling large objects in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I'm trying to do a project on object recognition using the CIFAR image dataset using R, however there is one problem with handling the dataset, when I read the data into some data frame or matrix, the object size for the objects gets large around 98MB, and this causes my program to run very slow, my code is vectorized but still I face performance issues. Please can someone suggest how can I resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: 98MB isn't that big.  What other packages/functions are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any package, just the regular data frame and matrix

Comment: It would help if you gave a bit more detail.  If you're just reading data in look at `fread()` in the data.table package.  If you're doing neural nets or stuff like that it's a different situation.

Comment: So the data that is provided is in a mat file, but I do not want to use Matlab for building my models, so I m using R.matlab package to read data from the mat file. I will be using neural networks for modeling, please can you suggest what should I do regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the binary form of those data would fit nicely into a flat-file type format, like that handled by bigmemory, ff, or rhdf5 packages.